# oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getSchema() exception

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying get the default database name from the connection for oracle

The following code gives me this abstract method error. Can anyone suggest me how I can get default database name using jdbc?

environmental information
version

```
oracle:Oracle 11g
java:1.8
```

pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

code

```
package snippet;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectiongetSchemaErrorTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx:8095/orcl";
    String user = "xx";
    String pswd = "xx";

    try {
      Class.forName(driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pswd);
      System.out.println(connection.getClass().getName());
      String schema = connection.getSchema();
      System.out.println(schema);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        connection.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

error

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getSchema()Ljava/lang/String;
    at snippet.ConnectiongetSchemaErrorTest.main(ConnectiongetSchemaErrorTest.java:24)
```

Answer (score 2):

`getSchema()` method is only available in `Java 7` and above but `ojdbc6.jar` is compiled with `Java 6`  where as `ojdbc8.jar` is compiled with `Java 8`. Either use `ojdbc8.jar` or alternatively you can try the code below with `ojdbc6.jar`

```
   // For ojdbc6.jar
   String schema= connection.getMetaData().getUserName();
   System.out.println("Schema Name is : " + schema);

   or 
 
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
   String schema=dbmd.getUserName();
   System.out.println("Schema Name is : " + schema);
```

Comment: thx 
```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The official supported Oracle JDBC versions from 11.2.0.4, 12.2.0.2, 18.3.0.0, 19.3.0.0,19.6.0.0, and 19.7.0.0 are available on [Central Maven Repository.](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/)
Refer to [Maven Central Guide](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) for more details.

It is recommended to use the latest version. Check out [FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) for JDK compatibility.